# Keeping a reference to a child element after elements been taken out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that modifies a child element. 
Later on, the child element gets appended somewhere else, but I still need a way of referencing it to the original parent.

For example..

My parent element has the class of item, and inside it is a child element with the class 'modal'. I though that, by binding this function in the beginning, 'var modal' would already have pointed to the elements child '.modal' so that when I call it later it doesn't matter where in the dom it is.. I'm wrong though.. Would using a closure inside the bind 'modal' function help me here?

See my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sw45W/

```
$('.item').bind('modal', function() {
   var modal = $(this).find('.modal');
   modal.hide(); // this doesn't hide as var modal doesn't seem to be cached
});

$('.item .modal').appendTo('#append'); // append these somewhere else

$('#item').trigger('modal'); //call the modal function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample if using closure.

```
$('.item').bind('modal', (function() {
    var modal = $(".item").find('.modal');
    return function(){
        modal.hide();
    };
})());

$('.item .modal').appendTo('#append');
$('#item').trigger('modal');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this..

I'm iterating though the items independently using 'this' as my reference, this way I can cache the child element I need, so that when I bind the event, I'm referencing the correct element.

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    // attach one event at a time
    var modal = $(this).find('.modal');
    $(this).bind('modal', function() { 
      modal.hide();
    });
});
$('.item .modal').appendTo('#append');
$('#item').trigger('modal');
```